# What to do when 6-month-old gets constipation?

Tags: infant, health, constipation

My 6-month-old starts to eat supplement food, but two days ago she stopped defecating, her nappies only had urine.

Is there anything we should have done to prevent this? Is there anything we can do for her at this stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constipation is a normal consequence to starting a diet supplemented with solids.  Particular foods can bind up your system: squash, zucchini, oats, rice and other foods high in fiber.  You can help constipation by eating foods that soften your daughter's stool like pureed prunes, apple sauce or pear sauce.  It is a balancing act, though because and loose movements could result if too much is given.  You will probably need to experiment based and alter her diet based on what you see.  If you daughter's constipation does not improve, you most definitely should consult your pediatrician for further advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try applesauce. Also maybe try different first foods, sounds like not enough fiber also.